# Cloud Functions for Firebase Endpoint to Process an Image

Tags: javascript, firebase, image-processing, multer, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a cloud function endpoint that can accept and process image files such as JPEG.  This is my code:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
//firebase complains that '/user_code/tmp' is read-only if I use this
//var upload = multer({ dest: 'tmp/' })
var upload = multer({
  storage: multer.MemoryStorage,
  fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024
});
var app = express()

app.post('/image-upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {

   console.log("request data: " + JSON.stringify(req.data));
   console.log("request params: " + JSON.stringify(req.params));
   console.log("request query: " + JSON.stringify(req.query));
   console.log("request body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
   console.log("request headers: " + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
   console.log("req.file: " + req.file);
   console.log("req.files: " + req.files);

   res.status(201).send(`My Server Response is ${req.file}`);
});

module.exports.testEndpoint = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

For some reason, req.file and req.files is always `undefined`.  However, req.body does appear to contain my image.  I am using Postman to send the HTTP POST request.

[image: Postman Input and Response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  My "Header" was incorrect.  Make sure to keep the `Content-Type` field unchecked.

[image: Uncheck Content-Type in Postman]